# Python 3.6.1 send and receive images as bytes via POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, byte, urllib

I am trying to send and receive a png image via Post.

I am trying to send like this:

```
 with bytes as <class 'bytes'> datatype

 def call(videoid, count, bytes):
  print(videoid)
  opener = request.build_opener()
  param = {'videoid' : '{0}'.format(videoid), 'count':'{0}'.format(count), 'bytes':'{0}'.format(bytes)}
  data=json.dumps(param).encode('utf8')
  req = request.Request(os.environ['ImageProcessURL'], data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  response = opener.open(req)
```

And the receiving part looks like this:

```
postreqdata = json.loads(open(os.environ['req']).read())
videoid = postreqdata['videoid']
count = postreqdata['count']
bytesstr = postreqdata['bytes']
```

But here bytes is now a string.
How can I convert it back to the original bytes type?